# ¿Cómo implementar un Chart con datos de una BD en React?

Tags: javascript, json, array, reactjs, chart.js

Estoy llenando un Chart en React con datos de una DB, sin embargo el chart no se dibuja correctamente pero si uso scorelocal[] si se dibuja correctamente.

Fotos: scorelocal=> http://rubbercorp.net/servicio/dash2.PNG
score=>http://rubbercorp.net/servicio/dash.PNG

```
var scorelocal = [55,60,70,55,60,70,65];
var score = [];
var ruta = "http://rubbercorp.net/servicio/tutorialchartjs.php";//
[{"playerid":"1","score":"63"},{"playerid":"2","score":"60"},
{"playerid":"3","score":"68"},{"playerid":"4","score":"60"}}]

export var areaChartData = {
  labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
  datasets: [
    fetch(ruta)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        for(var i in data) {
          score.push(data[i].score);
        }
    }),
    {
      label: '',
      data: score,
    }
  ]
}
```

¿Hay alguna alternativa a `array.push()`?

Answer (score 0):

Me es difícil saber del todo, ya que no muestras la lógica donde estás renderizando el gráfico ni tampoco mencionas la librería que estás usando, pero en `scorelocal` tienes un arreglo de números mientras que en `score` tienes un arreglo de strings.
Prueba cambiando en tu fetch:

```
score.push(Number.parseInt(data[i].score));
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. He encontrado una forma no "formal" y es cambiando la pestaña en el menú de la página(la página no se recarga en el navegador). Creo que se debe a que la interfaz se carga antes que los datos de la DB. ¿Cómo podría solucionar eso?

Comment: Insisto con lo que puse en mi respuesta, si no agregas información a tu pregunta o la planteas bien, es difícil que recibas la ayuda que requieres (como lo que te respondí, pero que en realidad no te sirvió). Revisa [ask] para que te hagas una idea de como puedes mejorar tu pregunta. Saludos